# React Native - Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

On my `Register.tsx` file I have the following code:

```
 <View style={styles.keyboardView}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            firstname: '',
            lastname: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
          }}
          onSubmit={values => {
            dispatch(authAction.registerUser(values))
              .then(() => {
                navigateTo('HomeScreen');
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          }}
          validationSchema={RegisterValidationSchema}>
```

Visual Studio code is highlighting `.then()` with the error: `Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>'.ts(2339)`

Additionally, `err` is also showing this error on visual studio code: `Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

Here's what my `store.js` code looks like:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk));

const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware);

export default store;
```

Notice that I am using `.js` file instead of `.tsx` file. So I am mixing both files. Does this cause the problem?

How do I solve this thing?

Answer (score 2):

That error is TypeScript specific error.

I guess, you are using dispatch from redux (please let me know if my guess is wrong). When you import it, try to add:

```
const dispatch:any = useDispatch()
```

and also, in your `catch`, try:

```
.catch((err:any) => console.log(err));
```

*Note: you can add any type as you need beside `any`, but I believe `any` would works too*